# C++ static function in template class

Tags: c++, templates, static

I want to place a static function inside of a template class for organizational reasons, not because the static function needs the template parameter. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Test {
    void print() const {
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
    }
    T var;

    template<typename G>
    static void sayHi(G&& g) {
        std::cout << "Hi! from " << g.print() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<std::string> t1{"Goodbye"};
    t1.print();
    Test::sayHi(t1);
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
error: 'Test' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
    Test::sayHi();
```

I understand why this is an error. Is there a different way I can try to pull this off? Does anyone have any alternatives?

I know the following works, however I don't want to have to specify the template parameter for that static call, specifically because that static method does not really on the template parameter `T` at all.

```
Test<std::string>::sayHi(t1);
```

Comment: `decltype(t1)::sayHi(t1)` or you could typedef a proxy `using TestInst = Test<char>;`, `TestInst::sayHi(t1);`.

Comment: Test<std::string>::sayHi(t1)

Comment: You can also do `t1.sayHi(t1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Test {
    void print() const {
        std::cout << var << std::endl;
    }
    T var;

    template<typename G>
    static void sayHi(G&& g) {
        std::cout << "Hi! from ";
        g.print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<std::string> t1{"Goodbye"};
    t1.print();
    Test<std::string>::sayHi( std::move( t1 ) );
}
```

For starters the function sayHi was defined incorrectly. And you need to specialize the class when the static function is called and use std::move for the lvalue to convert it to rvalue.

Comment: Should have been more specific, I don't want to have to specify the template parameter for that static call, specifically because that static method does not really on the template parameter `T` at all.

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment It is a class template. Its specialization for example even can have no  static function. You have to use the simple template id.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure hwat you mean by that?

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment You can specialize or partially specialize the class template such a way that it will not have the static function.